# Ubuntu touch flashing failed/taking to long. Black screen! Redeploy help!

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bootloader

So i'm brand new to the whole unlock, root and flashing thing.

I just tried flashing Ubuntu touch on my Galaxy Nexus (international GSM/HSPA+)
and everything seamed fine until the very end when i got this ERROR message.

**ERROR:phablet-flash:Installation is taking too long or an error occured along the way.**

I didn't know what to do so i disconnected my device (which was in Ubuntu recovery) and tried rebooting it from there, it worked "sort of".

i got the Google logo with the unlocked icon then it continued to a black screen.
In the installation guide on http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/install said i should:

"try wiping the /data partition on your device and redeploy".

the problem is that i don't know how to do this and i'm basically sitting here with a useless phone right now.

I would be extremely grateful for some proffeexpert help.

Answer (score 0):

To wipe the data on the phone, install a custom recovery mod, like Clockwork Mod Recovery or TWRP onto the phone. In CWM, you can format the partition by going to "Wipe Data/Factory Reset" then go to "Wipe Cache Partition" when you've finished those two, go to advanced and select "Wipe Dalvik Cache" then you should reboot, and proceed with flashing Ubuntu Touch. I have no experience with Ubuntu Touch or how to install it. But that's basic information on how to erase the data on your phone. It's probably best to erase everything then flash again. Follow instructions carefully when flashing the rom on your phone.

Comment: thanks, the only thing i still a little confused with is the need to get CWM since i can already clean the space "sort of" and clean the cache from the ubuntu touch bootloader...
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B719bHUKExaIS1BWRzMwdGZrQTQ/edit?usp=sharing
+ the ubuntu recover/bootloader thing is based of CWM

Comment: Ah, well since that is based off of CWM, you should be able to just do the same process then. As long as it has the same 3 options that I listed above. I haven't used Ubuntu Touch yet so I was unaware that it's recovery was based off of CWM